# Symfony route variables as an associative array in the controller function

Tags: php, arrays, interface, symfony

I have lots of generic controllers that will have get, update and delete routes however they will have different route parameters. I want to find a way for all the controllers to implement a generic interface but I can't because the signatures for the parameters are different.

For example, right now I have the interface like so:

```
interface iTable
{
    public function getAction(Request $request, $token, $sortBy, $order, $searchBy, $searchQuery, $pageNumber);
    ...
```

and an appropriate controller

```
class UserManagementController extends Controller implements iTable
{  
    /**
     * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users", name="ManagementGetUsers")
     * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithPage")
     * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSort")
     * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndPage")
     * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/searchBy={searchBy}/q={searchQuery}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndSearchAndPage")
     */
    public function getAction(Request $request, $token = '', $sortBy = "Id", $order = "ASC", $searchBy = 'Id', $searchQuery = '', $pageNumber = 1){ 
    ...
```

Is there a way for me to combine the parameters in the routes in an associative array so that i can implement an interface with an options array that encapsulates all the route parameters?

```
interface iTable
{
    public function getAction(Request $request, array $options);
    ...
```

**Update 1**
I'm trying to specify the default parameters in the method annotations so that the method only needs the `$request` parameters.

```
/**
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users", name="ManagementGetUsers", defaults={"token" = null, "sortBy" = 'Id', "order" = 'ASC', "searchBy" = 'Id', "searchQuery" = null, "pageNumber" = 1})
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithPage", defaults={"token" = null, "sortBy" = 'Id', "order" = 'ASC', "searchBy" = 'Id', "searchQuery" = null, "pageNumber" = 1})
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSort", defaults={"token" = null, "sortBy" = 'Id', "order" = 'ASC', "searchBy" = 'Id', "searchQuery" = null, "pageNumber" = 1})
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndPage", defaults={"token" = null, "sortBy" = 'Id', "order" = 'ASC', "searchBy" = 'Id', "searchQuery" = null, "pageNumber" = 1})
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/searchBy={searchBy}/q={searchQuery}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndSearchAndPage", defaults={"token" = null, "sortBy" = 'Id', "order" = 'ASC', "searchBy" = 'Id', "searchQuery" = null, "pageNumber" = 1})
 */
public function getAction(Request $request){   
...
```

But I am getting the following error

```
[Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 102 in method AppBundle\Controller\UserManagementController::getAction()
```

I've tried playing around with the parameter defaults for the different routes but with little success.

Comment: Take a look at $request->query->all();  I suspect you maybe over complicating things but if you are already planning on passing the request then there really is no need to pass the parameters as an array.  Might want to take a look at some of the other generic crud bundles to see how they do it.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, I'm having a look at that now using default values in the annotations and ```$request``` as the only controller method parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem by using `$request->attributes->get('...');`

```
/**
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users", name="ManagementGetUsers")
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithPage")
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSort")
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndPage")
 * @Route("/token={token}/manage/users/sort={sortBy}/{order}/searchBy={searchBy}/q={searchQuery}/page{pageNumber}", name="ManagementGetUsersWithSortAndSearchAndPage")
 */
public function getAction(Request $request){
    var_dump($request->attributes->get('token'); // Will output correctly
    ...
```

Using this approach I can retrieve all the custom parameter tokens and maintain a consistent controller method signature for the generic interface.